# Why all anchor tags get style when I limit styles only to anchors inside list?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, zurb-foundation

I have a list `<ul>` that is on the top of my page.
Lists are in the div tags.
Problem is that I need to set some css style only to the `<a>` inside one of those lists with class `.menu-social-icons` styles is on the bottom of question.
But when I add style like I wrote bellow all `<a>` tags on page get these stylings.
I have no idea why it propagates to all links.
Is there something wrong with my CSS styling?
This is my HTML ouput:

```
<div class="full-width top-page-bar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="left">
                <ul class="right inline-list menu-social-icons show-for-large-up">                  
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="right"> 
              <ul class="no-bullet inline-list right account-holder">

                <li><a id="registerLink" title="Register" class="SkinObject" href="#">Register</a>
</li>
                <li><a id="loginLink" title="Login" class="LoginLink" href="#">Login</a>
</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the style that raises an issue:

```
.menu-social-icons li a, a:link, a.visited, a.active {
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
color: #ff0000;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 20px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
margin: 0 5px;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 35px;
background: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-social-icons li a:hover {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad: `.menu-social-icons li a, a:link, a.visited, a.active`

Good: `.menu-social-icons li a, .menu-social-icons li a:link, .menu-social-icons li  a.visited, .menu-social-icons li a.active`

Full example:

```css
.menu-social-icons li a, .menu-social-icons li a:link, .menu-social-icons li  a.visited, .menu-social-icons li a.active {
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
color: #ff0000;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 20px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
margin: 0 5px;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 35px;
background: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-social-icons li a:hover {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width top-page-bar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="left">
                <ul class="right inline-list menu-social-icons show-for-large-up">                  
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="right"> 
              <ul class="no-bullet inline-list right account-holder">

                <li><a id="registerLink" title="Register" class="SkinObject" href="#">Register</a>
</li>
                <li><a id="loginLink" title="Login" class="LoginLink" href="#">Login</a>
</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This selector is the problem: `.menu-social-icons li a, a:link, a.visited, a.active`
It is being applied to a:link, a.visited and a.active. You have to scope them too, like this:

`.menu-social-icons li a, .menu-social-icons li a:link, .menu-social-icons li a.visited, .menu-social-icons li a.active`

Answer (score 1):

also add .menu-social-icons to remaining a:link a:visited a.active or the will apply to all the `<a>`

```
   .menu-social-icons li a, a:link, a.visited, a.active {
            border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
            color: #ff0000;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 35px;
            background: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

to this

```
    .menu-social-icons li a, .menu-social-icons li a:link, .menu-social-icons a.visited, a.active {
            border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
            color: #ff0000;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 35px;
            background: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css declaration is not doing what you think it is. This line

```
.menu-social-icons li a, a:link, a.visited, a.active {
```

applies the style to `.menu-social-icons li a`, and to any links in the `link`, `visited`, or `active` state.

To fix the problem, you need to use the following:

```
.menu-social-icons li a, .menu-social-icons li a:link,
.menu-social-icons li a.visited, .menu-social-icons li a.active {
```